# For loop in VBA Code

Tags: vba, excel, for-loop

NOTE: I was able to upload a link to a picture in the comments.

I am using a for loop in an excel macro in an attempt to compile data.

I have the following VBA code:

```
Sub MoveData()
'
' MoveData Macro
'

'
Dim rng As Range
Set rng = Macro.Application.Range("R1:X1000")
With rng


    For i = 1 To 200
        a = 5 * i
        b = i + 1

        Range(a, 18).Select
        Selection.Copy
        Range(b, 3).Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste

    Next i

End With

End Sub
```

I get the following error message:
Run-time error '424':

Object required

Any clarification would be much appreciated! I've been stumped on this for quite a while!

Comment: are copying and pasting in the same sheet? and these ranges `Range(a,18)` and `Range(b,3)` are always the same?

Comment: try changing this `Macro.Application.Range` to this `ActiveSheet.Range`

Comment: Yes, I am copying and pasting in the same sheet. I will always be copying from columns R:X and pasting in columns C:I

Comment: @braX when I make that change I get a new error message, Run-time error '1004':

Method 'Range' of object '_Global' failed

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/km8Ke.png Here is a link to the screenshots. I want the top photo to look like the bottom photo.

Comment: you define `rng` but you arent using it anywhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this and make sure your values are on the activesheet.

```
Sub MoveData()

    Dim rng As Range

    Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("R1:X1000")

    With rng
        For i = 1 To 200
            a = 5 * i
            b = i + 1

            Debug.Print "copying from =>" & .Cells(b, 3).Address
            Debug.Print "copyting to =>" & .Cells(a, 18).Address

            Stop 'and take a look at the immediate window
            ' what is there?

            .Cells(b, 3) = .Cells(a, 18)
        Next i
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: For some reason, that just seemed to remove column t of my data.

Comment: @Emma - try to code again. Take a look at the immediate window every time the code stops.

Comment: Every round, it prints out: copying from =>$T$2
copying to =>$AI$5

Comment: Ok. Then try to adjust it a bit to what you want, by changing `a`, `b`, `3` and `18`, @Emma

Comment: After I changed the range from A1:X1000, the first column transferred successfully. Many thanks :D

Comment: @Emma  - congrats for managing to fix it! :) Feel free to mark the answer as selected, by clicking on the green check next to it :)

Comment: Thank you so much! (I'm new!)